# Where did the particles to shrink this come from?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

As [this question says](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/211053/where-did-the-extra-pym-particles-come-from-in-endgame), in *Avengers: Endgame*, there were just enough particles

> for <strike>two</strike> one test run and everyone to be able to get to the past and back.

But before they actually leave, Rocket hands Clint a shrunken *Benatar*.

Where did the particles to shrink it come from?

Comment: it could be possible that they counted the pym particles for the trip excluding the ones needed to shrink benatar.

Answer (score 4):

### Ant-Man's shrinking disks, probably

I think it's reasonable to think he still had some discs on him when he left the Quantum Realm.

In various scenes of *Ant-Man*, you can see that his shrinking/enbiggening discs are stored in pouches on his hips, for instance when he grabs the enbiggening disc to get out of the Quantum Realm:

In the post-credits scene of *Ant-Man and the Wasp*, Scott also has these pouches equipped when he goes to gather healing quantum particles:

Then, he will still have them when he comes out in *Avengers: Endgame*. True, there's no evidence these pouches actually contained them, but it's not a strecth to think it, either:

- the discs are small, easy to carry around. Why not take some?
- one of these discs, albeit a blue one (shrinking's red), saved his life once. Again, why not take some?

Comment: That seems reasonable, but wouldn’t they also be Powered by Pym(tm)?

Comment: @Bobson yeah? That doesn't mean they could have reverse-engineered them to get particles, though. Maybe they're embedded into the disc in such a way that they can only be used as that... discs.